# NavigationContainer react native

Tags: react-native, expo

i'm getting this error with react native :

> "Looks like you have nested a 'NavigationContainer' inside another. Normally you need only one container at the root of the app, so this was probably an error. If this was intentional, pass 'independent={true}' explicitly. Note that this will make the child navigators disconnected from the parent and you won't be able to navigate between them."

It's the only file where there is NavigationContainer, and this component is at the root, so I don't understand why i'm getting this error..

[index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbYA0.png)

Tried to create App.js, but don't worked

Comment: could you press `cmd + shift+ F` and find `NavigationContainer`, the warning say you have many `NavigationContainer` inside other `NavigationContainer`

Comment: @famfamfam this isn't the problem, I only have one NavigationContainer that is in my index.js

Comment: could you make a sample git with same error,  I can help u, your informations is not enough

Answer (score -1):

take a look at this image, change the component Regiter, is using the same Login component as the Login Route and try again. [image]

Comment: it changed nothing, I have the same error

Comment: if you share the project on snack or github I can take a look on it.